# How to access a site with shared IP using IP address (and sub-folders? URL?)

Tags: dns, denial-of-service

`http://www.dokuwiki.org` is down at the moment as their DNS server is under a DDOS attack.  I have found the site's IP is `http://138.201.137.132/`, however this IP is shared among multiple sub-domains, accessing the above IP via a browser gives the list of possible subdomains as:

```
www.dokuwiki.org
forum.dokuwiki.org
bugs.dokuwiki.org
irc.dokuwiki.org
pluginwiz.dokuwiki.org
xref.dokuwiki.org
update.dokuwiki.org
search.dokuwiki.org
donate.dokuwiki.org
translate.dokuwiki.org
```

I'm thinking that it should be possible to access these if the subdomain folder of the site is known, eg

```
http://138.201.137.132/dokuwiki/www
```

Is this correct?

If so, is there any way to determine the URL to access the site using the IP address?  I'm guessing we'd need to be able to read the .htaccess file, which is off limits.

Comment: I suggest masking the IP address for safety. Answerers will be able to understand and answer your question just fine without knowing the actual IP address.

Comment: If they're under DDOS attack - its probably worth waiting for things to get sorted out first or finding/accessing a mirror/cached version of the site

Comment: Hi @ShaneBishop Just wondering how does masking the IP address make it safer? I took some care to determine this is dokuwiki's IP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you put entries into your hosts file and had host resolution set to files before DNS.

But first - where'd you get that IP? You would be opening your wiki to attack if it's not the correct one.

I looked at it from a non-privileged environment and it *looks* right, but anyone can make a site that looks right

Comment: @betsys What do you mean "You would be opening your wiki to attack if it's not the correct one."?  My dokuwiki is hosted on my own server; this is dokuwiki's documentation and software download site.  I'm just after some documentation on syntax, a good option is the internet archive, which I've upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just exchange the DNS-name for the IP. The server needs to know the DNS-name of the server you are trying to reach (if it's not the "default server"). You can either use the hostfile or a local DNS server to resolve the DNS to an IP (make sure to delete any residual DNS cache from the brower, OS, etc.), then just try to access the site as you would do normaly with the URL.